# What Frameworks and imports are necessary to use AVAudioPlayer on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a sound on iOS using AVAudioPlayer. I added the AVFoundation.framework and MediaPlayer.framework and tried to import AVAudioPlayer.h (this part didn't work), but I still can't instantiate the AVAudioPlayer class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), AVAudioPlayer has been available since iOS 2.2.

Make sure you're using the following import:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
```